# What is the best way to draw "new items count"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I need to implement this mockap [image]

It's no problem with gray logos. It's TextView with PNG files in TableLayout.

But, I don't know, how to put small green circle on corner of one. This circle means "there is new messages, what need your attention". It can be, or not. It can contain different numbers.

My idea - to draw MyView with circle (I have it in PNG too) and number. But how can I calculate coordinates of "parent's" corner?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` to put new items counter above the corner of gray icon. For example the following xml is single cell in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gray_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/some_gray_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_items_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/gray_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/gray_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/green_circle_icon"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to move counter up or more to right use margins with negative values.

```
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
```

With this approach you have to update counter value and visibility from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ViewBadger`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) library that allows you to do such thing with few lines of code.